# Wordpress theme- the fallback image in header that is loaded before the video media has loaded keeps reappearing at start of the looped video

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, image-fallback

Using WordPress free theme- Clean Portfolio Free. I have a video looped as the main header. There is the option of uploading a fallback image that should just appear once while the video is downloading. However, this image keeps reappearing at the start of each loop play of the video.
Is there a work around for this? I cannot find the specific script/ coding that might be used to edit this.
Many thanks
Davey

I cannot find the specific script/ coding that might be used to edit this. There is no support for the free theme so I am trying to sort it out myself.